# Query between SQL server and Client side

Tags: sql

I create a query: Select * from HR_Tsalary where month='3' and year ='2010'  the result is 473 records and I found 2 duplicate record, then I create another query to find duplicate record only: SELECT Emp_No, COUNT(*) FROM HR_Tsalary WHERE year = '10' AND month = '3'GROUP BY   Emp_No HAVING COUNT(*) > 1  the result is zero record from client side (thru Visual Basic Adodb code). But when I use same query from server the result is 2 records. Is there any different when create a query between from server side and client side?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2691403/sql-2000-some-functions-from-client-side-not-working

Answer (score 0):

You could start SQL Server Profiler then run your VB code, and see the exact query that's hitting the database and make sure it is what you're expecting.

-Krip

Answer (score 0):

SQL server profile is always open also I identified that from client side some functions are working such as select, order by but some functions are not working such as group by, sum, count, having

Comment: SQL server profile is always open also I identified that from client side some syntax are working such as select, order by where, but some syntax are not working such as group by, sum, count, having